# Angular 2, split large binary file in chunks with FileReader and send to php

Tags: angular, upload, filereader, chunked

I'm trying to create a service that splits a big file in chunks and send it to a php page that reassemble it.

```
@Injectable()
export class FileSplitterService {
  private serviceName: String = "FileSplitterService";



  public file: File;
  public fileSize: number;

  private chunkSize: number = 64*1024;
  private offset: number = 0;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    console.log(this.serviceName + ' - constructor');
  }
  startSplit(event) {
    console.log(this.serviceName + ' - startSplit');

    /**
     * Initialize offset and file stuffs
     */
    this.file = event.files[0];
    this.fileSize = this.file.size;
    this.offset = 0;
    console.log(this.serviceName + ' - startSplit',this.file,this.fileSize,this.offset);
    /**
     * Start reading file
     */
    this.chunkReaderBlock();
  }

  readEventHandler(evt) {
    console.log(this.serviceName + ' - readEventHandler',evt);
    if (evt.target.error == null) {
      this.offset += evt.target.result.length;

      /**
       * send chunk
       *
       */
      this._http.post("https://10.134.77.77/web2/api/uploadFile.php",evt.target.result)
      .map(res => <any>res      )
      .subscribe(res=>{
        if (this.offset >= this.fileSize) {
          console.log(this.serviceName + ' - Done reading file');
        } else{
          // read next chunk
          console.log(this.serviceName + ' - readEventHandler -> read next chunk', this.offset);
          this.chunkReaderBlock();
        }
      });



    } else {
      console.log(this.serviceName + ' - Read error: ' + evt.target.error);
      return;
    }

  }

  chunkReaderBlock() {
    console.log(this.serviceName + ' - chunkReaderBlock', this.offset, this.chunkSize, this.file);
    var r: FileReader = new FileReader();
    var blob = this.file.slice(this.offset, this.chunkSize + this.offset);
    r.onload = (e) => {
      console.log(this.serviceName + ' - onload',e);
      this.readEventHandler(e)
    };

    r.readAsText(blob);
  }

}
```

This first version of my service works well with big text files, but the problems comes when I try to split binary files (like videos) using **readAsArrayBuffer** method of FileReader (instead of readAsText). It seems that after first reading, the onLoad function returns an empty event object.
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you pass the File object directly to a post request with Angulars HttpClient (and enabling progress monitoring)?